# How to make responsive dynamic menu in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

How to make responsive dynamic menu in asp.net mvc.I have 3 level in that menu.1 level is menu , 2 level is sub menu and last level is sub to sub menu.those data came from database.I already tried to responsive menu but it not ok.I want that menu bar with `data-toggle="collapse"` style.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="mainnav">
    <div class="menu">
      @Html.Action("MenuLayout", "Menu")
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background:#68c2fe;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
      <nav id='cssmenu'>
        <ul id="ul_1">
          @{ foreach (var dr in Model) {
          <li>
            <a href='#'>@dr.MainMenuName</a> @{ ((POS_System.Controllers.MenuController)this.ViewContext.Controller).get_Submenu(dr.ID.ToString()); }
            <ul>
              @{ foreach (POS_System.Models.SubMenu subitem in Session["submenu"] as List
              <POS_System.Models.SubMenu>) {

                <li>
                  <a href='#'>@subitem.SubMenuName</a> @{ ((POS_System.Controllers.MenuController)this.ViewContext.Controller).get_Subtosubmenu((subitem.ID).ToString(), Session["RoleId"] == null ? string.Empty : Session["RoleId"].ToString()); }
                  <ul>
                    @{ foreach (POS_System.Models.SubToSubMenu subtosubitem in Session["subtosubmenu"] as List
                    <POS_System.Models.SubToSubMenu>) {
                      <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink(@subtosubitem.Description, "Index", @subtosubitem.SubToSubMenuName)
                      </li>

                      } }

                  </ul>

                </li>

                } }
            </ul>

          </li>

          } }

        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you're trying to build a bootstrap-style collapsible navbar, then for a start your content will need to be inside the "navbar" element and generally conform to bootstrap's template and classes (which you can find in their documentation). Right now you seem to have put all your logic in a separate div.

Comment: Thank bro !!! If you have a sample. Please share me !! :D

Comment: Like I said, it's in the bootstrap documentation. Docs for Bootstrap 4.0 here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ . You just need to get your Razor code to produce HTML which is compatible and gives you the desired structure. N.B. If you're using Bootstrap 3.x you can find the docs for that separately by searching

Comment: OK bro !!! Thank you so much !!! :D

Comment: No problem...but in future try to google thing first for yourself, a _lot_ of things are already available online